# Can hydrogen peroxide be oxygenated?

Tags: solutions, home-experiment

As per the heading, would peroxide be able to dissolve oxygen by whatever method, to have free oxygen and hydrogen peroxide mixed (under pressure?) similarly to $\ce{CO2}$ or $\ce{O2}$ in water?  I understand peroxide is trying to break down  & would produce similar over time anyway, though with a loss of peroxide. Question is just for the sake of knowing, no pressing need. Thanks...

Comment: In general, all gases have some non-zero solubility in any solvent. It is generally a small number. The amount of gas dissolved also depends on the partial pressure of that gas. So, sure, why not?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume hydrogen peroxide solution (often 3%) is quite similar to water in its ability to dissolve oxygen and carbon dioxide, then yes some oxygen is always dissolved in the solution at STP.

However, the amount of carbon dioxide that can dissolve in water is much higher as compared to oxygen. Carbon dioxide reacts with water to form carbonic acid and that drives water to dissolve something like 25 times more (according to a cursory internet search) carbon dioxide than water under similar conditions.

Secondly, the addition of hydrogen peroxide to the water, which is constantly decomposing to produce free oxygen, would lead the solution to dissolve even less atmospheric oxygen than normal water.

So, yes, it dissolves some. Nowhere near similar to carbon dioxide. I'm not sure it would be useful in any context where it might compare to soda water =)

This is really what hydrogen peroxide already is if it wasn't for the brown bottle slowing down the decomposition. You would see slow bubbles of "fizz" as the peroxide gradually goes "flat."

Now higher concentrations of peroxide would release more oxygen and can be quite dangerous. Lab quality 30% solutions are corrosive, strong oxidizers, and can be an explosion risk. But the oxygen still would not remain dissolved in the water for long, thus the danger. They have special handling precautions and even special expandable "accordion" containers for storage.

Interesting to think about...